# How can I assert query params in cypress using form data?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I am testing search functionality in one of my Cypress tests and having trouble getting to all parts of the request url. On my page, I have a form that a user can enter a number to search for. When a user clicks "Search", the system makes an ajax request with the appropriate data. Everything is working great.

In my Cypress test, I'm intercepting a `GET` request in one of my tests like this:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/api/v1/foo/?include=**').as('myRequest');

...
```

That is the `GET` request that is made when a user clicks the submit button to search.

Within my test, I am entering text into a text field like this:

```
...

cy.get('[data-cy="number"]').type('12345');
```

The text is getting properly interred into the input.
Next, I am triggering an ajax request like this:

```
...

cy.get('[data-cy="search"]').should('exist').click();

cy.wait('@myRequest').then((interception) => {
    console.log(interception.request.url); // /api/v1/forms/?include=foo <-- does not have filter[number]...
    expect(interception.request.url).to
    .include('filter[number]=12345');
});
```

When submitting a real request (not through cypress) the request url looks like this:

```
https://example.com/api/v1/foo/?include=bar&filter[number]=12345
```

However, when cypress makes the request, it's seemingly not picking up the query field and my test is failing.

I've also tried using `expect(interception.request.query)` but it is always `undefined`.

How can I properly pick up the `filter[number]` query param in my test?

Comment: Maybe the endpoint is not triggered with the typed value. May be you can try this `cy.get('[data-cy="number"]').type('12345').trigger('input')` and then intercept.

Comment: Hmmm. No luck. When I look at the network tab, I can see the query param getting added. I just seems isolated to Cypress that it can't "pick it up".

Comment: Another option would be to play around with the URL in `cy.intercept` if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's preceding requests that are using up your `cy.wait('@myRequest')`.

Query parameter matching is a bit tricky, but it works using a routeMatcher function and checking for the correct params, then assigning a dynamic alias.

```js
cy.intercept('/api/v1/foo/?include=**', (req) => {
  if (req.query.include === 'bar' && req.query["filter[number]"] === '12345') {
    req.alias = 'myRequest'   // alias for only these parameters
  }
  req.continue()
})

cy.get('[data-cy="search"]').should('exist').click();

cy.wait('@myRequest').then((interception) => {
  ...

})
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue I found. There was an `@wait` command that was nested further upstream I didn't catch. Once I moved my following `@wait` further into my test, things worked as needed. Thank you so much for your time!